# Where's the documentation for making Bluetooth SPP connections to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mfi, spp

Prevailing wisdom seems to indicate that, in order to make an SPP (Serial Port Profile aka. RFCOMM) connection over Bluetooth Classic, from a peripheral to an iOS device, the peripheral needs the Apple Authentication Chip (AAC, aka. an MFi chip).

Note that for technical reasons, Bluetooth LE is a nogo.

Problem is, that I haven't actually been able to find any firm information about this, just a bunch of posts saying it. I've checked Apple's docs for the MFi chip and program, to no avail.

Is this information only accessible through the MFi program. We're a member, but I haven't personally checked it out.

Edit 06NOV2015: iOS devices **do not** support SPP, and most likely never will. To get something similar, you have to go the MFi way, on which I can't really comment much, due to inch-thick NDAs...

Answer (score 0):

MFi documentation is only available to MFi members and is protected by NDA, general public shouldn't have access to it.